# iOS: How can i get location names of multiple longitudes and latitudes when data is coming from web service as a response?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-maps, reverse-geocoding

I need to help with my code. I am getting longitudes and latitudes as a response from a web service. I need to convert them to a location name and show it in respective table view cell label.
Following are the response, code and screen shot of my view where I show my converted city, country name, and correct my code where i am doing mistake.

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "JobTableViewCell.h"
#import "SlideNavigationController.h"
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface JobPostedViewController : UIViewController <SlideNavigationControllerDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray* job_id;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray* assigned_user_id;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray* job_title;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray* job_description;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray* job_priority;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* job_longitude;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray* date;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* job_latitude;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray* job_completed;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray* job_start_date;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray* bids;

@property (nonatomic, strong) CLGeocoder *myGeocoder;

- (IBAction)onClickJobButton:(id)sender;


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *sideNavigation;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *jobPostedTableView;

@end
`

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.jobPostedTableView.dataSource = self;

    //Slide Navigation
    [self.sideNavigation addTarget:[SlideNavigationController sharedInstance] action:@selector(toggleLeftMenu) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    WebManager *manager = [WebManager sharedInstance];
    [manager getJobPostedWithCompletionBlock:^(id response){
        NSDictionary *dictionary = (NSDictionary *)response;

        // Read data from JSON
        NSDictionary *responseObject = [dictionary objectForKey:@"response"];
        NSLog(@"The Array%@",responseObject);

        self.bids = [responseObject objectForKey:@"bids"];
        self.job_description = [responseObject objectForKey:@"job_description"];
        self.job_id = [responseObject objectForKey:@"job_id"];
        self.job_completed = [responseObject objectForKey:@"job_completed"];
        self.job_latitude = [responseObject objectForKey:@"job_latitude"];
        self.job_longitude = [responseObject objectForKey:@"job_longitude"];
        self.job_priority = [responseObject objectForKey:@"job_priority"];
        self.job_start_date = [responseObject objectForKey:@"job_start_date"];
        self.job_title = [responseObject objectForKey:@"job_title"];

        [self.jobPostedTableView reloadData];
    }];

        CLGeocoder *ceo = [[CLGeocoder alloc]init];
        CLLocation *loc = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:[self.job_latitude floatValue] longitude:[self.job_longitude floatValue]]; //insert your coordinates

        [ceo reverseGeocodeLocation:loc
                  completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
                      CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                      NSLog(@"placemark %@",placemark);
                      //String to hold address
                      [[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
                      NSLog(@"addressDictionary %@", placemark.addressDictionary);
                      NSArray *ar = [placemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:@"locality"];
                      NSLog(@"placemark %@",ar); // Extract the city name
                      NSLog(@"placemark %@",placemark.country);  // Give Country Name

                  }

         ];
    }


#pragma mark - SlideNavigationController Methods

- (BOOL)slideNavigationControllerShouldDisplayLeftMenu
{

    return YES;
}

#pragma mark - TableView Data Source

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.job_title count];
}

- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableview:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"JobTableViewCell";
    JobTableViewCell *cell = (JobTableViewCell *)[self.jobPostedTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil) {

        cell = [[JobTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    // Comparing array string to display an urgent image
    if ([[self.job_priority objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
         isEqualToString:@"urgent"]) {
        cell.urgentLabel.hidden = NO;
    } else {
            cell.urgentLabel.hidden = YES;
    }
    // Condition whether job completed is open or closed
    if ([[self.job_completed objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
         isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
        cell.jobStatus.text = @"Open";
        [cell.jobStatus setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(84/255.f) green:(56/255.f) blue:(255/255.f) alpha:1.0f]];
        cell.flagImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"jobPosted_opened.PNG"];
    } else {
        cell.jobStatus.text = @"Closed";
        [cell.jobStatus setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(179/255.f) green:(179/255.f) blue:(180/255.f) alpha:1.0f]];
        cell.flagImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"jobPosted_closed.PNG"];
    }


    cell.jobTitle.text = [self.job_title objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.jobContent.text = [self.job_description objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.bidsLabel.text = [[self.bids objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]stringValue];
    return cell;

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Comment: Isn't the `reverseGeocodeLocation:completionHandler:` doing the job for you? As a good practice if you're accessing the first object of an array try to use `placemarks.firstObject` instead of `[placemarks objectAtIndex:0]` (which is = `placemarks[0]`) - to prevent an out-of-bounds crash if the array is `nil` or empty.

Comment: i want to show all the lat and long in their cells, how can i edit in my code to get that results, kindly suggest me i am beginner to iOS?

Comment: The easiest way would be to create another array (`jobLocationNames`?) and add there reversed `lat`s and `lng`s in a loop. Also, looks like your structure is a little incorrect: instead of getting an array of of `job` objects you're getting an array of arrays for each property of your `job` object (and accessing them by index). An easy way would be for you to create a sample project and upload to github so we can help you.

Comment: thanks i am very thankful to you i you will provide me a code or some helpful material because i am working on it since last two three days and haven't get a desire results.

Comment: No problem, update your question with the link and we'll go from there.

Comment: Some time reverseGeocodeLocation:completionHandler: is not give proper result. In some country it show only country name for example Nepal,Pakistan etc. So i think you need to find some other solution too.

Comment: @IslamQ. kindly i have edited my code check now and i can not provide you a link because i don't have permissions to provide any code outside office kindly help me from here. Thanks and sorry Happy Eid Greetings

Comment: @chiragshah ok thanks by chance one of my location i am getting from response is AHMADABAD INDIA

Comment: Do you receive only 1 `lat` and 1 `lng` from the server?

Comment: @IslamQ. No, lat and lng are dynamic at the moment i am receiving more than 20 but i am getting one location name against these lat , lng.

Comment: but from this code it looks like you're getting only one: `CLLocation *loc = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:[self.job_latitude floatValue] longitude:[self.job_longitude floatValue]];`

Comment: @IslamQ. That's the problem i am facing despite after much effort i can't implement good logic i am getting lat lng in string and give it to CCLocation, what i want to do is get them in Array and pass it one by one.

Comment: Can you post an example of a response from the server?

Comment: @IslamQ. did you check the response?

Comment: Yes, will post the solution as an answer soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution:

1. Change `NSString` to `NSArray` of these `properties`:

   ```
   @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* job_longitude;
   @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* job_latitude;
   ```

---

2. Add a new `property` to hold the geocode results:

   ```
   @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary* reversedGeocodes;
   ```

---

3. Set `reversedGeocodes` in `viewDidLoad:` method:

   ```
   self.reversedGeocodes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
   ```

---

4. Add this method to get the reversed geoCode (and save it for the future):

   ```
   - (void)locationNameWithLat:(float)lat
                           lng:(float)lng
             completionHandler:(void (^)(NSString *locationName, NSError *error))completion
   {
       if (!lat || !lng)
           completion(@"Unknown location", nil);

       if (!completion || !lat || !lng)
           return;

       NSString *latStr = @(lat).description;
       NSString *lngStr = @(lng).description;

       // For each pair of lat and lng creating a unique key and saving the result
       // so we don't have to process the same pair multiple times.
       // Example:
       // lat = 23.039567; lng = 72.566004;
       // key = @"23.03956772.566004"; value would be whatever CoreLocation returns
       NSString *key = [latStr stringByAppendingString:lngStr];

       if (key.length) {
           if ([self.reversedGeocodes[key] length]) {
               completion (self.reversedGeocodes[key], nil);
           } else {
               self.reversedGeocodes[key] = @"Loading...";
               CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
               CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat longitude:lng];

               [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location
                              completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
                                  if (error) {
                                      completion(@"Unknown location", error);
                                  } else {
                                      CLPlacemark *placemark = placemarks.firstObject;
                                      NSString *locationName = placemark.country; // Default = country

                                      if (placemark.locality.length) // add city if available
                                          locationName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", placemark.locality, placemark.country];

                                      self.reversedGeocodes[key] = locationName.length ? locationName : @"Unknown location";

                                      completion(self.reversedGeocodes[key], nil);
                                  }
                              }
                ];
           }
       } else {
           completion(@"Unknown location", nil);
       }
   }
   ```

---

5. Call the above method from `cellForRowAtIndexPat:` method before your return the `cell`:

   ```
   float lat = self.job_latitude[indexPath.row];
   float lng = self.job_longitude[indexPath.row];

   [self locationNameWithLat:lat
                         lng:lng
           completionHandler:^(NSString *locationName, NSError *error) {
               cell.locationName.text = locationName;
           }];

   return cell;
   ```

---

P.S. Let me know if I missed anything or misspelled because I typed some of the code on here...

Comment: this is the best way of populating tableview with address from given list of latitude and longitude which are fetched from web services . i am searching since two days regarding reverse geocoding but couldnt come up with the way of using . your code gave me the idea of solving the issue and how to use that method to get desired result .

Comment: @Moxarth I'm glad I could help.

Comment: now i am facing some unexpected error . compiler is not going in [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location ..... ] ; . i am passing the lat lon and even i checked the data is available in CLLocation * location . everything was working fine but suddenly it stops executing geocoder block . any solution you might think of ?

Comment: actually , i am developing app , where i have to fetch all lat lon from webservice and get address from it and store that address into the database , so that address we can use it further in process . in populating table your code works fine . but when fetching lat lon from webservice and calling your method locationNameWithLat: with lat lon , it does not show address and i could not store it into array . i am on this since 2 days , but could not find proper way . if you would find out regarding this then let me know please . thanks for your help .

Comment: i am seeing that geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location block is getting executed at the end of the all code execution . so we can not get location string address value in middle of code execution or in between thread execution . so i am wondering how to get address from given lat lon and store into database .

Comment: @Moxarth, sorry for a delayed response: I'm not sure if I understand you problem correctly. Can you create a new ticket with your issue so we can take a look at that?